# TTY Font Resets on Reboot

Tags: fonts, tty, virtual-console

My TTY font doesn't persist over a reboot. Even after running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` and choosing a font, if I reboot, it resets to whatever ugly thing the default is. What do I do to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems setupcon doesn't run automatically, so you'll have to either run it manually or put it in your `.(ba|z|fi|etc)shrc` or something like that. If you use Byobu, put it immediately before the Byobu line and add `2>/dev/null` to keep it from complaining every time you open a new shell.